# How to test code that uses browsers APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using **Node** for running my **unit-tests**.

I have a JavaScript module run in the browser I'd like to test.

My code is "**isomorphic**", i.e. it avoids language features not available in Node, like `export`s.

But it uses pure browsers APIs: `XMLHttpRequest`, `FormData` and `File`.
I have found Node's implementations for each of them.
But the one of `XMLHttpRequest` does not support **upload**.

So I'm looking for the simplest way to unit-test this code in an environment with these APIs.
The code does not need DOM or other browsers APIs, "only" these three.

I've already used **PhantomJS** for other needs but:

- this will create another test workflow (minor issue),
- it supports an older JavaScript version and it would force a complete rewrite of the code to test (major issue),
- the code has a lot of NPM dependencies that probably won't be compatible (blocking issue).

As the code is **Browserified** all these issues may disappear but before going along this way I'd like to be sure.

Is there any chance to get it work with **PhantomJS**, **CasperJS** or the like?

Which other alternatives are available?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you test code that runs in a browser. If it runs in a browser, it needs to be tested in a browser.

You need to look into solutions based on the webdriver spec. The big hairy monster in this ecosystem is Selenium. I'm currently researching this topic because of some issues we've had with using selenium-server. You should also look into Nightwatch and Leadfoot. Webdriver.io is the first recommendation a lot of people recommend, as its a node-based client that wraps (poorly) around Selenium. But the documentation is all over the place and we've run into frequent bugs using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1
I agree that to 100% test the behavior of this code it should be run into a browser.
But it's far easier to test in Node to grasp 99% of the bugs, this is what I do for most of my code.
I'll check **WebDriver.io** as it seems the nearest to my needs. :-)

Comment: I'd actually recommend going with Nightwatch. We've been using webdriver.io for a couple months and its problematic pretty often. Currently planning a switch to NW.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll use it if need be. :-)